# A basis for the topology of $\mathbb{C}^ \times $ on which exp: $C ^ \infty (U)\to C^\infty(U)^\times$ is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

What I'm trying to find is a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ for which whenever U is an element of the basis and $f$ is a holomorphic function without zeroes, then $f$ can be written as $e^g$ for some holomorphic $g$ on $U$.

I guess what I'm looking for is a basis on which a log function is defined, but since I need to take log$(f(z))$, for every possible $f$, I'm not quite sure how to ensure that log is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a nonvanishing holomorphic function defined on a simply connected open set $U$, then $f$ has a holomorphic logarithm.  The trick to prove this is to note that locally, $\log f$ is an antiderivative of $f'/f$.  So, to find a global logarithm, you can just integrate $f'/f$.  That is, define $$g(z)=\int_a^s\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}\,ds+C$$ for some fixed point $a\in U$ and some $C$ which is a logarithm of $f(a)$, where the integral is taken along some path from $a$ to $z$ in $U$.  The integral will be independent of the path chosen because $U$ is simply connected (and $f$ never vanishes so the integrand is holomorphic on $U$), and so will give an antiderivative of $f'/f$ defined on all of $U$.  By the choice of $C$, $\exp(g)=f$ near $a$ and thus everywhere since $U$ is connected.

So, you can take your basis to consist of the simply connected open sets, or just the open balls if you prefer.

Comment: You probably meant a path from $a$ to $z$, right? I actually had the same idea for the proof, but it seems to me that in order for the proof to work we would need to show that exp$(g(z))$ satisfies the same cauchy problem as exp$(g(z))$, ie that $f(a)=$exp$(g(a))$ (which is clear), and that $f'(z)=$exp$(g(z))'$, but the latter is the case if and only if exp$(g(z))=f(z)$, making the argument circular.

Comment: Locally near any point $p$, there is a function $\log(f)$ (just use some branch of the logarithm defined near $f(p)$).  The derivative of this function is $f'/f$.  So, any other function $g$ whose derivative is $f'/f$ differs from that local $\log(f)$ function by a constant.  This means that every point has a neighborhood on which $\exp(g)$ differs from $f$ by a constant factor.  This constant factor is $1$ at $a$, so it must be $1$ everywhere by connectedness.

Comment: Another way to see this is to differentiate the *quotient* $\exp(g)/f$ and get $0$, so the quotient is constant.