# Principal logarithm of the Gamma function: an elementary approach?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms, gamma-function

I have been trying to learn about the Gamma function and it's properties from various sources. As is common practice, I am defining the Gamma function by the formula
$$\Gamma(s):= \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{s-1} \, dt$$
for $\Re(s)>0$, and its meromorphic continuation to the whole plane by the Weierstrass product formula
$$\frac1{s\Gamma(s)} = e^{\gamma s} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+s/n) e^{-s/n},$$
with $\gamma$ denoting the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

In most places, I have noticed that people directly start talking about the principal branch of $\log \Gamma(s)$ (giving its series and discussing Stirling's formula) for $s \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R_{\le 0}$. However, this is defined and holomorphic only when $\Gamma(s) \not\in \mathbb R_{\le 0}$ for any $s \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R_{\le 0}$. It is not clear to me why this latter assertion holds except for in the obvious cases where $s>0$, and I would very much appreciate any help in that regard. I have tried seeing it as a consequence of the Weierstrass product and have also tried combining the aforementioned integral representation of $\Gamma(s)$ with the functional equation $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ but to no avail. I feel like I am missing something really straightforward or am having trouble putting the pieces together in the right manner.

Comment: What is it that is giving trouble? Is it that the principal branch of $\log(\Gamma(x))$ "is defined and holomorphic only when $\Gamma(s)\not\in\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$ for any $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$"? Is it why this holds for $s$ other than $s\gt0$? Is it something else?

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for your response. I had misunderstood the branch of $\log \Gamma(s)$; I was under the impression that it had to be the principal branch (defined on $\mathbb C - \mathbb R_{\le 0}$) in order for it to satisfy the following version of Stirling's formula: $$\log \Gamma(s) = \left (s- \frac12 \right) \log s - s + \frac12 \log(2\pi) +O\left(\frac1{|s|}\right)$$ as $|s| \rightarrow \infty, |\arg(s)| \le \pi - \delta$. However, as pointed out by Eric Wofsey, it is the branch defined by the infinite series obtained by taking the logarithm of the standard Weierstrass factorization.

Comment: @robjohn I guess it might still be a slightly interesting side question whether $\Gamma(\mathbb C - \mathbb R_{\le 0}) \subset \mathbb C - \mathbb R_{\le 0}$; if that were the case then the principal branch of $\log \Gamma(s)$ would be defined and holomorphic on $\mathbb C - \mathbb R_{\le 0}$ (in which case I think it woukd coincide with the infinite series definition). But I now think that is probably not the case (although I can't immediately think of a counterexample).

Comment: Unfortunately, $\Gamma(z)\in\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$ for some $z\not\in\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$.

Comment: Another product representation is $\Gamma(1+x)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{k+x}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^x$

Comment: The border between the red and white parts of [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe29E.png) is where $\Gamma(z)\le0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know that $\Gamma(s)\not\in\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ for $s\not\in\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ to define the logarithm (indeed, I don't think that is even true).  Instead, you can just "formally" take a logarithm of the product formula, turning the product into a sum.  That is, take $$\Gamma(s)=\frac{e^{-\gamma s}}{s}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+s/n)^{-1}e^{s/n}$$ and take the logarithm factor-by-factor to define $$\log\Gamma(s)=-\gamma s -\log(s)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(s/n-\log(1+s/n))$$ where on the right side you use the principal branch of the logarithm on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ (which makes sense because if $s\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ then $1+s/n\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ as well).  The sum converges locally uniformly so this function is holomorphic, and exponentiating it gives you back $\Gamma(s)$.  Also, it is easy to see that if $s>0$ then this $\log \Gamma(s)$ is the usual real-valued logarithm, so this is the unique analytic continuation of the real-valued $\log \Gamma(s)$ function for $s>0$ to all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$.

Alternatively, there is a general theorem that if $f$ is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function on a simply connected domain, then $f$ has a well-defined holomorphic logarithm (defined by integrating the logarithmic derivative $f'/f$; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4551160/86856) for more details).  So in order to define $\log\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$, you only need to know that it is nonvanishing on this domain, since $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ is simply connected.

Comment: Ah great, thank you! Just one follow up, so if I understand correctly, the branch of the logarithm on which Stirling's formula holds is the one given uniquely by the series $$\log\Gamma(s)=-\gamma s -\log(s)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(s/n-\log(1+s/n))$$ that you mentioned, is that correct? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure what exact statement of Stirling's formula you are asking about, but I would think it doesn't matter, since if you use a different branch of the logarithm that just changes it by a constant, which doesn't matter for the asymptotics.

Comment: I meant the following version of Stirling: $$\log \Gamma(s) = \left (s- \frac12 \right) \log s - s + \frac12 \log(2\pi) +O\left(\frac1{|s|}\right)$$ as $|s| \rightarrow \infty$, $|\arg(s)| \le \pi - \delta$ for some fixed $\delta>0$ (c.f. Davenport, "Multiplicative Number Theory", chapter 10, page 73, equation (6)).

Comment: Ah OK, with a $O(1/|s|)$ error term you do care about constants then, so yes, that should be for this principal branch of the logarithm.

Comment: Yes that was indeed my question, thanks again.